# How to format text in a shiny app using css which is used in rmd file

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have the shiny app below and I try to use css in order to format with the given parameters (fonts,font, sizes, distances between paragraphs). I have used `tags` method in order to use css but it does not seem to work.
**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      <style type="text/css">
  body{
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: "Montserrat Light", sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: linen;
}
  H1.title{
  font-size: 44pt;
  font-family: "Chronicle Display Light", Times, serif;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: linen;
}
  H1{
  font-size: 44pt;
  font-family: "Chronicle Display Light", Times, serif;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: linen;
}
  H2{
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Chronicle Display Light", Times, serif;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: linen;
}
</style>
    '))),
    fluidRow(column(3,h3("Concent"))),
    tags$hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3,h5(strong("Investigators")))),
    fluidRow(column(9,"The investigators of this project are:")),
    fluidRow(column(9,"Dr Adam Hodgkins","(",tags$a (href="adam@hodgkins.com.au","adam@hodgkins.com.au"),")")),
    fluidRow(column(9,"Dr Hodgkins can be contacted by telephone on 0414 296 699. ")),
    tags$hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3,h5(strong("Consent")))),
    fluidRow(column(12,"The practice owners have been given information about the research project titled “Life, death and statins: Survival analysis of elderly general practice patients in relation to statin prescriptions.”")),
    fluidRow(column(12,"The practice owners have been provided the opportunity to discuss the research with the investigators who are conducting this research as part of the University of Wollongong. ")),
    fluidRow(column(12,"The practice owners have been advised of any possible risks or burdens associated with this research and have had the opportunity to ask the investigators any questions they may have about the research and my participation.


")),
    tags$hr(),
    fluidRow(column(12,"I understand our practice’s participation is voluntary, our practice is free to choose not to participate and is free to withdraw from the research at any time. Our practice’s choice to not participate or to withdraw consent will not affect its relationship with the researchers or the University of Wollongong. 


")),
    tags$hr(),
    fluidRow(column(12,"I understand that if our practice chooses to participate in this study, an authorised staff member will be asked to run an analysis tool which will extract de-identified data from the electronic health record (Best Practice Premier), analyse the data in order to produce a report for the practice, and send encrypted, de-identified data to the investigators.



")),
    tags$hr(),
    fluidRow(column(12,"I understand that any data extracted from the electronic health record will not, under any circumstances, contain names or identifying characteristics of any individual. Likewise, no information that could lead to the identification of our practice will be disclosed in any reports on the project, or to any other party. 




")),
    tags$hr(),
    fluidRow(column(12,"I understand that completion of the following details will constitute a valid consent for involvement in this research project.
I declare that I am authorised to give consent for our practice to participate in research projects.




"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be a bit experimental, you can use [bslib](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/). It allows to easily create themes that can be used in `shiny` and `markdown`.

If you want to reuse the CSS you've written for the `markdown`, you can create a CSS file in the `www` directory and copy the CSS. Then use `tags$link` in the `dashboardBody` to use the CSS file. For more information see the shiny tutorials [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css) and [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

In the CSS for the `shiny` app, you need to remove the `<style type="text/css">` tags at the beginning and end to make it work.

Comment: I have used tags method but I cannot make it work. I have put the css inside the app as you can see in the edited code.

Comment: You've had superfluous tags in your CSS file

Comment: maybe you can help with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65510715/apply-css-formating-only-on-specific-tabitem-of-a-shiny-dashboard